# Javascript: Run callback list, one by one

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-analytics

The actual code:

Given the data

```
var triggers = {
    'send.ga' : { /* data */ },
    'reload.wnd' : {/* data */}
};

// [...] this = jQuery(document)

for( var _call in triggers ){
    if( data.hasOwnProperty( _call ) ){
        this.trigger( _call , data[ _call ] );
    }
}
```

> An popup window sends a message to the parent/main window with this data. I use this approach on login with Google+ / Facebook (OAuth)

So it happens that I send & trigger 2 events on `document`

1. check for and call google analytics for an event record
2. do a page refresh `window.location.reload()`

The problem is that these two runs (almost) simultaneously and sometimes the call to GA don't get to be executed as the page reloads.

My goal is to manage somehow to observe when first event completes so I can run the second, and so on. What if I use `$.ajax` in calbacks? How about another functions call?

So far I tried $.triggerHadler but with no success.

What do you suggest?

Comment: @Anonymous0day nope... :|

Comment: is that a code you own and you can modify or not ?

Comment: Because your not managing your own callbacks but instead triggering events on other third partly libraries there isn't a way of knowing when those events have completed unless the third party lib offers an API for such situations. Does the send.ga event library offer callbacks, promises, or some 'done' event you can hook into? If not your options are rather limited.

Comment: Yes, it seems this is the only way - to use the 'done' callbacks of third party libraries. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

<s>The solution was to use [$.Deffered() Object](https://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/).</s>

Here is a simplified code that may serve as a start for who needs it:

```
(function($){

    // ... push the events to trigger into an array
    var events = [
        {
            'n': 'send.ga', // trigger name
            'd': { /* trigger data */ },
            's': $( document ) // trigger element/scope
        } /* ... more... */
    ];

    // define the function to run for each event
    function runEvent( index ){
        // start with the first element
        if( !index ) index = 0;
        // get current event
        var event = events[ index ];
        $.Deferred()
            // run next event when done
                .done( function(){
                    // check for the next event & call for it
                    ( index + 1 < events.length ) && runEvent( index + 1 )
                } )
            // run current event
                .resolve( event[ 's' ].trigger( event[ 'n' ], event[ 'd' ] ) );
    }

    // run the events queue
    runEvent();

})(jQuery);
```

Anyway, I had to modify the original callbacks trigger functions as using third party libraries (or when it is not reliable to modify some code) which uses ajax or some other asynchronous calls it is not possible to 'observe' when they are completed. So I had to use callback options of those libraries to manage the queue of events execution.

Comment: The resolution of the Deferred is synchronous and so kinda defeats the purpose of using Deferred. Especially since your not returning the Deferred. Why is it needed? I think a recursive for loop wold serve better and be more readable.

Comment: I have asked you > Using Promise ?? < you told no, but finally it is yes ! good point

Comment: Yes, it is! Thank you!